# PHP loop: How can I repeat this loop after it happend once

Tags: php, loops, symfony

So I have this loop

```
         {% if employees %}
             {% set count = 1 %}
                 {% set multiplier = 1 %}
                    {% for employeeIndex, employee in employees %}
                         <tr>
                            <td>{{ employee.werknemers }}</td>
                            {% for workdayIndex, workday in workdays %}
                                {% if (employeeIndex * multiplier) ==  workdayIndex %}
                                 <td>x</td>
                                 {% if count == (employees|length) %}
                                    {% set multiplier = multiplier * employees|length %}
                                    {% set count = count + 1 %}
                                 {% endif %}
                                {% else %}
                                    <td></td>
                                {% endif %}
                          {% endfor %}
                         </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
```

The result is this : 
[image]

What I want too happen is for the loop too repeat it self after every employee has a date assigned to them. As u can see the first X begins at 3 and goes down too 13. What I want is the X to begin from 14 again and go down the same way. This should be possible in Twig I believe. Thanks for helping out!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not test this because I can't right now test twig but I think this should work

```
{% if employees %}
    {% set employeeCount = (employees|length) %}
    {% for employeeIndex, employee in employees %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ employee.werknemers }}</td>
            {% for workdayIndex, workday in workdays %}
                {% if (workdayIndex - employeeIndex) is divisible by (employeeCount) %}
                    <td>x</td>
                {% else %}
                    <td></td>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what i'm look for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey @Donjedi Do you have some time for me to answer another question on this matter?

Comment: Ok thanks man. So lets say Angelo can't work on day 4 ( see image above ) then I would want for someone to take over for him. So in this case that would be the person that has to work the following day (5) 'Arjen' . Do you know how I could achieve this? @Donjedi

Comment: Oh and one more thing. Those days when someone can't work are registered in a database @Donjedi

Comment: I really think a logic like that should come from Backend to your frondend and you just parse for each employee and check (X) the designated day. Can that be achieved? If not I can try and "hack" some stuff in twig